# Arquivo CSV no excel não importa pro MYSQL

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel, import

Estou tentando importar meu arquivo .CSV do Excel para o MYSQL e quando declaro a primeira variável ID int ele não reconhece, engraçado que quando coloco o ID int no final ou ate mesmo uso insert(com o ID int como a primeira coluna) ele aceita. Como será que resolvo isso?

Obs: ele acusa o erro 1366.

> Incorrect integer value ... for column 'ID' at row 1.

O script ficou:

```
Create table teste_2(id int,nome varchar(100), n2 float, n3 float, n4 float, n5 float, n6 float, n7 float);


Load data infile 'local do doc'
INTO TABLE teste_2
Fields terminated by ','
Enclosed by '"'
Lines terminated by '\n';

Select * from teste_2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Muito provavelmente o seu arquivo csv possui cabeçalho, para tratar este problema pode adicionar o comando, ao trecho que código que importa o csv:

```
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Repare que aqui isso é um comando e o número 1 é apenas um exemplo de valor, você por ignorar um número arbitrário de linhas.

Segundo a documentação:

> A cláusula IGNORE <número> LINES pode ser usada para ignorar linhas no
> início do arquivo. Por exemplo, você pode usar IGNORE 1 LINES para
> pular uma linha de cabeçalho inicial contendo nomes de coluna

Seu trecho do SQL para importar o csv deve ficar assim:

```
Load data infile 'local do doc'
INTO TABLE teste_2
Fields terminated by ','
Enclosed by '"'
Lines terminated by '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Qualquer problema consulte a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Sim, tentei o comando IGNORE deste mesmo modo que você colocou, mas o problema parece que está no reconhecimento da variável int que eu declaro, o que é muito estranho pelo fato de os números dessa variável irem somente de 1 a 12. Será que é alguma biblioteca ou regulação do mysql que não está certa?

Comment: oi @RafaelTanque, se mensagem de erro mudou, então o problema já é outro.

Comment: @RafaelTanque você pode abrir uma nova pergunta explicando em detalhes o que aconteceu e o qual a nova mensagem de erro